# PostgreSQL select now()::timestamp differs from default now()::timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, utc, current-time

In my program every table has a column `last_modified`:

```
last_modified int8 DEFAULT (date_part('epoch'::text, now()::timestamp) * (1000)::double precision) NOT NULL
```

For update I added a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sync_lastmodified() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.last_modified := (date_part('epoch'::text, now()::timestamp) * (1000)::double precision);

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER
  sync_lastmodified
BEFORE UPDATE ON
  ourtable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  sync_lastmodified();
```

They should write current time as a long value into the `last_modified` column on update/insert.
However, it is not working as I expected.

To reproduce the issue, I did update and got the following:

```
last_modified value equals 1543576224455 (Friday November 30, 2018 16:10:24 (pm) in time zone Asia/Tashkent (+05))
```

Almost at the same time I run the function `now` from pgAdmin:

```
SELECT now()
```

and got the result:

```
2018-11-30 11:10:36.891426+05
```

To check system time within a few seconds I run `timedatectl status` from terminal and got the following result:

[image]

> The question is why the function now() gives a time with 5 hours
>   difference when I run it from trigger or as a default value when
>   insert?

Comment: Because of the issue I am getting wrong results when select values depending on last_modified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epoch` will give you the number of seconds since the epoch. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) says:

> `epoch`
>
> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative)

Since you are offset by 5 hours from UTC, that explains the difference.